How many minutes the Apollo astronauts had to wait from splashdown until the first frogmen touched the CM?
The distance between the target point to the splashdown were remarkable small, 3 nautical miles or less. The distance to the recovery ships were small too.
How many minutes the crews had to wait from splashdown until the first frogmen touched the CM?

Based on Apollo by the Numbers elapsed time from splashdown to "flotation collar inflated"  was usually less than 20 minutes.

Navy swimmers jumped from a recovery helicopter into the water near the command module to stabilize it. They attached and inflated around it a custom-made flotation collar.

Times shown are Ground Elapsed Time.



Apollo
Splashdown
Flotation Collar Inflated
Delta T




7
260:09:03
260:41:00
00:31:57


8
147:00:42
148:07:00
01:06:18


9
241:00:54
241:14:00
00:13:06


10
192:03:23
192:21:00
00:17:37


11
195:18:35
195:32:00
00:13:25


12
244:36:25
244:53:00
00:16:35


13
142:54:41
143:11:00
00:16:19


14
216:01:58
216:17:00
00:15:02


15
295:11:53
?
?


16
265:51:05
266:06:00
00:14:55


17
301:51:59
302:08:00
00:16:01



Apollo 8 was an outlier, and the document does not give times for flotation collar inflation or hatch opening for Apollo 15.
Back off a few minutes for "touch time" to allow attaching the collar.

I don't know if this'll be helpful in future or not, but I have a go-to-spreadsheet formula I use to make StackExchange tables, as in this spreadsheet, cells M2 through M9.  It automatically adds "blank cells" to each side of the actual data range to make the table borders, and it's easy to copy paste in the row of dashes, etc.

@ErinAnne Many thanks. What I just did was a painful, thumb-fingered cell-by-cell cut and paste. I would be glad not to to that again.
